# Работа скрипта с правами администратора

Tags: python, реестр

Хочу написать скрипт, который после запуска ПК будет выполнять некоторые махинации в реестре, а именно в разделе политики. Я пользовался winreg чтобы задавать нужное значение при определенных условиях, но когда запускал скрипт - получал отказ в доступе. Пользовался pyqadmin и elevate, скрипт работал, но вылазило окно подтверждения (скрин ниже). Какие есть способы запуска скрипта без подтверждения? Можно ли как-то обойти этот этап?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нельзя, потому что это было бы слишком небезопасно. Ну и логично, что редактировать политики имеет право только администратор

Comment: @andreymal запускаю скрипт, предварительно дав ему права админа, все работает, только это окошко вылазит. Нашел фикс - изменение параметров контроля до последнего уровня. Может можно было бы как-то занести данный скрипт в какой-то белый список, чтобы не менять параметры чисто из-за него?

Comment: Нельзя, даже у встроенных программ винды нет таких привилегий

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**
Решил путём нажатия Подробнее - спуск ползунка в самый низ, т.е отключаем все ограничения.